# Aurelia CollectionObserver handler is not triggered when collection is changed

Tags: typescript, web-component, aurelia

I have an Aurelia component that is just supposed to display a list of items. The component's model has an "items" property which is bindable:

```
@bindable items = [];
```

The component template displays the list using a simple repeat attribute:

```
 <div repeat.for="item of items">  
    ${item.id}   </div>
```

When I push a new item in my bound array from the page's viewmodel where the component is used, I can see the item being added as the list is refreshed and the new item appears. 
My problem is that I need to perform other actions when the 'items' array is modified so I tried to add a collectionObserver to the component like this:

```
import {BindingEngine, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(BindingEngine) 
export class GridControl {   

  @bindable items = [];

  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.items = []; 
    let subscription = bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.items)
                                    .subscribe(this.listChanged);   
  }

  listChanged(splices) {
    // do some stuff   
  } 
}
```

But my 'listChanged' handler never gets called. Any idea why?

Comment: Wondering if this is a subtle JS scoping issue - just try `.subscribe(splices => this.listChanged(splices))` instead and see if that works... other than that, it looks ok to me. What version of Aurelia?

Comment: I bet Charleh is right. I've had to do that a lot in my Aurelia apps.

Comment: @Charleh, this was not a scope problem but, as I said in my answer below, I still had to rescope the callback as you proposed here in order to keep the reference to the component... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the constructor, `bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.items)` is called.

Later, when the component is data-bound, `this.items` is assigned a different array instance via the data-binding. This different array instance is not the one you passed to the binding engine for observation.

Try doing something like this:

```js
import {BindingEngine, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(BindingEngine) 
export class GridControl {   
  @bindable items;

  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
  }

  listChanged(splices) {
    // do some stuff   
  }

  subscribeItems() {
    if (this.items) {
      this.subscription = this.bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.items)
        .subscribe(splices => this.listChanged(splices));
    }
  }

  unsubscribeItems() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.dispose();
      this.subscription = null;
    }
  }

  itemsChanged() {
    this.unsubscribeItems();
    this.subscribeItems();
  }

  unbind() {
    this.unsubscribeItems();
  }
}
```

Comment: Guess I missed that one, when it happened..
If only there were some kind of constant changelog coming our way (-:

Comment: itemsChanged() is for the case where items gets assigned a completely new array?

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think of this... I just had to rescope the callback to listChanged in the subscribe method (.subscribe(splice => this.listchanged(splice)) in order to keep the reference to the component but apart from that, your solution is gold.